# Application Insights missing dependencies tracking for WCF services

Tags: wcf, azure-application-insights

I am using Application Insights tracking for a WCF service but I cannot see which specific operation was called and more important I cannot see which database operation/http calls were executed as part of the WCF operation.

I see only that a specific WCF services "**.svc**" was called using **POST**

For example, clicking on a transaction, I cannot see executed Database calls(which are executed inside of the WCF operation):
[image]

For other similar Web Api Applications I can see database calls/http calls correctly.

I added Application Insights with nuget package manager the same way I did for other **Web API** applications where it works correctly. So I assume that WCF needs some special configuration for application insights.

Does **WCF** services need some special configuration to be more discoverable by Application Insights?

Comment: What is the version and framework of your Application?

Comment: It is a WCF service with .NET Framework 4.7.2

Comment: Can you please share the code?

Comment: Please share the code of your `Progarm.cs` file on how you are configuring the ApplicationInsights and `appsettings.json` file configuration.

Comment: There is a .NET WCF application, not .NET core. Means there is only a web.config file and an ApplicationInsights.config file where ApplicationInsights is configured. I have added a screenshot with the included packages in web.config. The applicationinsights has default values.

Comment: I dont see any packages related to Application Insights here in `web.config` file.Can you please share the packages which are in your `.csproj`

Comment: I added another image with web.config. The app insights configuration is visible in ApplicationInsights.config which has default values except the Connectionstring. I added an image also for this in the description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you taken a look at [ApplicationInsights-SDK Labs](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-SDK-Labs/blob/master/WCF/readme.md)

You might have better luck collecting the necessary information by adding the labs NuGet source:

`https://www.myget.org/F/applicationinsights-sdk-labs/api/v3/index.json`

and installing the

`Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Wcf` NuGet package (remember to enable pre-release packages when selecting)

You will then need to instrument your WCF service using `[ServiceTelemetry]` attribute for your service class. You can also opt to use the `<serviceTelemetry>` service behaviour when configuring your service.

You can check out more details information regarding the configuration to control the collection of operation telemetry [here.](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-SDK-Labs/tree/master/WCF)

EDIT: Some kind sould has taken it upon themselves to fork and update the library to run on newer frameworks. You might want to take a look [here.](https://github.com/spyder007/ApplicationInsights-SDK-Labs/tree/feature/net462)

Comment: I must say that I asked support from Microsoft, and I got the same answer: to use this ApplicationInsights-SDK Labs solution you mentioned. For me, it worked with the [ServiceTelemetry] attribute, the solution with <serviceTelemetry> in web.config didn't work in my case because it made my web.config invalid. I wonder still why there is not an official release of this nuget package, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Wcf has just a BUIL version "0.28.0-build06820" and seems it will not get any future updates because it's archived. Hopefully this is safe to use in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem today, our app insight instance was missing dependencies of outgoing http calls. I upgraded to the latest version and now http calls work but WCF dependencies gone missing. I downgraded Application Insight packages to version 2.9.1 and now both http and WCF are being collected, full SQL command also works. Using deprecated verions is not ideal but I rather do that than adding custom nuget source and fighting with build pipeline.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, You can use Message logging in wcf service trace.

WCF uses the tracing mechanism defined in the System.Diagnostics namespace. Trace consumers create trace listeners for the trace sources for which they want to retrieve information like this:

```
<system.diagnostics>
<sources>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="All">
    <listeners>
      <add name="xmlTraceListener"/>
    </listeners>
  </source>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="All">
    <listeners>
      <add name="xmlTraceListener"/>
      <add name="textBoxListener"/>
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
<sharedListeners>
  <add name="xmlTraceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="ClientLogBasic.svclog"/>
  <add name="textBoxListener" type="WinTransmitterClient.MyTraceListener, WinTransmitterClient" initializeData=""/>
</sharedListeners>
<trace autoflush="true"/>
```

**PS**: The name of the `<listeners>` tag needs to be the same as the name of `<sharedListeners>`. And in `<sharedListeners>` type should include full class name with namespace and assembly name.

The resulting traces and message logs are viewed using [Service Trace Viewer Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/service-trace-viewer-tool-svctraceviewer-exe). You can refer to [Tracing and Message Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/tracing-and-message-logging) for more detailed info.

Comment: This configuration is not related to Azure Application Insights I need something specifically for Azure